# How can i read specific text from txt file in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a simple dictionary which searches the words from txt file. I created the txt file and stored some English words. I want to write the word to EditText. Then, this word will be found and displayed on the TextView. Here is my code. It displays the whole txt file. How can i find the specific word ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//creating variables
TextView myText;
EditText myEdit;
Button myButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //initializing the TextView EditText and Button
    myText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.idTextView);
    myEdit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.idEditText);
    myButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.idButton);


    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String saveData=myEdit.getText().toString();
            try{
            myText.setText(readfile());
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });

}

private String  readfile()throws IOException {     

    String str="";          
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.translate);    
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line=reader.readLine();

    while (line!=null)
    {   
        str = str + line + "\n";
        line = reader.readLine();

    }
    reader.close();

    return str;

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how your `readFile()` is implemented. I suggest that you modify it to accept a `String` parameter. That way, it will search for that word in the file and return its meaning as another `String` that you can assign to `TextView` via `setText()`

```
myText.setText(readFile(saveData)));
```

is how the suggested implementation would look like.

---

Inside this method, when you read the file line-by-line, check if the `String` you just read from the file contains the required word. This can be done using the `contains()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Think you're after a simple `contains()` check:

```
String fileText = readFile();

Boolean textFound = fileText.contains(saveData);
```

If that boolean is true, then you would display the value of `saveData` in the box. You could put this operation in a loop and search for multiple words as well if you wanted.